# MySQL bug with LIKE clause?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL InnoDB table called Courses with a column called "name".

I have a record in this table with the name "NVQ Level 3 Diploma in Achieving Excellence in Sports Performance".

When I execute this statement:

```
SELECT * FROM Courses where name like '%NVQ Level 3 Diploma in Achieving Excellence in Sports Performance%';
```

It returns 0 rows.

However, LIKE clauses like the following: "NVQ Level 3", "Diploma in Achieving" and "Sports Performance" etc... I get my record returned.

I don't understand why this wouldn't work.

Comment: can you try with `like '%in Achieving Excellence in %'` ? Maybe there is a problem in number of blanks.

Comment: Number of blanks, or one of the blanks actually being a TAB, would be my guess, too.

Comment: Or perhaps a mistake with capitalisation? Try using just lower case inside your quotes and wrapping `name` in `LOWER`, i.e. `where LOWER(name) like '%nvq level 3 diploma in achievi...`

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that the field you are trying to query is too or has the wrong name.

Please check what type of field you are trying to query (maybe the String gets cut off) + double check for Typing errors.

Answer (score 0):

False alarm... thanks for your contributions but I found that the user who entered the course name put two spaces in after the number three. GIGO.